# how to set app.config key value?

Tags: c#, app-config, key-value

I want to set some keys in .NET console application's app.config file.

Like :

```
<add key="Success" value="<Status>Success</Status>"/>
<add key="Error"   value="<Status>Error</Status>"/>
```

But it's not allowing me to do that set values in <> brackets.Can we set key values like this ?

Comment: You will have to escape them like `&gt;`and `&lt;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the escape characters for greater than and less than symbols as below:-

```
<add key="Success" value="&lt;Status&gt;Success&lt;/Status&gt;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your `<` and `>`, like this

```
<add key="Success" value="&lt;Status&gt;Success&lt;/Status&gt;"/>
<add key="Error"   value="&lt;Status&gt;Error&lt;/Status&gt;"/>
```

Note that forward slash in the `</Status>` should be OK and doesn't need to be escaped.